# How to use log4j with Spring 5?

Tags: spring, log4j

I have troubled with using Log4j in Spring 5. In the past, I used Log4j in Spring like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And now, I want to use Log4j in Spring 5, but there is no class named 'org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener'. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just need you put log4j.properties file in your classpath. then you will get your result.

Comment: I have log4j/xml in different path , how to register that into spring 5.0 ?

Comment: Better use log4j outside about package war/ear .
Then reply about comment @Arunprasad

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring 4.2.1 documentation, Log4jConfigListener is deprecated in favor of Apache Log4j 2 (following Apache's EOL declaration for log4j 1.x). So, I've removed  section with this class from web.xml and then everything went fine. Also I've added log4j.properties to the "util:properties" section of applicationContext.xml.